# Solve differential equation $(x^2 + y^2 + x)dx + ydy = 0$ by making a variable substitution or by turning it into a total differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation $(x^2 + y^2 + x)dx + ydy = 0$ by making a variable substitution or by turning it into a total differential equation. I tried various substitutions. For example this equation is equivalent to $(x^2+y^2)dx + d(xy) = 0$ so I tried substituting with $(x,y) \to (x, u=xy)$ so the equation becomes $(x^2 + \dfrac{u^2}{x^2})dx + d(u) = 0$. If I rewrite this as $u' + \dfrac{u^2}{x^2} = -x^2$ then it is a Ricatti differential equation, though I can't find any solution for this equation. For example, it seemed logical trying for $u = x^\alpha$, but $\alpha x^{\alpha-1} + x^{2\alpha-2}=-x^2$ doesn't say much to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's ***Riccati***. The Italian word “ricatti” is the plural of “ricatto”, that is, *blackmail*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:
$$xdx+ydy =\dfrac 12 d(x^2+y^2)$$
Don't confuse with:
$$d(xy)=xdy+ydx$$
The DE is separable with the substitution $u=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Oh.. thanks, I keep making silly mistakes like this